# "Privacy" is a required value

Tags: checkout, error, form-validation

I am getting the following error while completing the second step (billing address) on checkout page:

"Privacy" is a required value.

I cannot see any Privacy field.

could you please suggest me what I may have messed up.

ADD: I have also checked HTML source code for the checkout page but cannot find any reference to Privacy on the page.

Just found that I get this message in the new account registration form as well. I am also not able to see the agree to terms and conditions checkbox on registration page. It seems this is disabled some how.

Comment: check the HTMl source code for a field which is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely an extension added a new attribute to the customer address entity, but didn't add it to any of the forms.
Here is how you can check. Run this query on the db.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    eav_attribute 
WHERE 
    frontend_label LIKE '%Privacy%' AND 
    entity_type_id IN (
        SELECT 
            entity_type_id 
        FROM 
            eav_entity_type 
        WHERE 
            entity_type_code = 'customer_address'
     )
```

This should return a row. If you don't need this field, just delete it, but backup first.
Or you can just set the value for `is_required` to 0 for the record you see.

Comment: Excellent, I am really thankful to you. Before posting this question, I invested 3 days to find out the reason. Thanks a lot...